# Google Map API version 2 Failed to contact Google servers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have started to create a demo app that uses Google Map Api V2, I followed the  Google guide http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html & http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-mapfragment-example/.

**The map activity is loading, but actual Google map is not loading, with error message:**

06-18 10:19:23.717: I/Google Maps Android API(29990): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

06-18 10:19:38.903: E/Google Maps Android API(29990): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Could the error be caused due to the fact that I'm on **3G/Edge** which is slower **than 4G or Wifi**, in turn be might causing the connection to timeout???

**Below is my Activity:**

```
package com.example.theappdallas;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MapViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap map = null; 
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);

         map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}//end class
```

**Below is my layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/map_view_directions" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/map_view_pin" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/map_view_search" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Below is my manifest(I have set all permissions & provided a new API key):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.theappdallas"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

       <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
       <!-- permissions -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <!-- SplashScreen -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4452000" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.theappdallas.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- API key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="*************************" />


        <!-- MainMenuActivity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.theappdallas.MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <!-- MapViewActivity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.theappdallas.MapViewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map_view" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Screenshot of the MapViewActivity:**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the map is not showing due to a connection timeout; the problem is most likely the API key.  [I would follow these instructions closely to make sure you are generating the API key correctly.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key)  Let me know if you have any specific questions regarding the process.  Also, you should remove your API key from code that you post.